# Output .map files for typescript to specific folder in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

I configured my IntelliJ IDEA to compile all .ts file to specific folder. Here's the configuration:

[image]

It works just fine. Here's my folder structure:

```
js/
  | - typescript/
        | - __test.ts
  | - __test.js
  | - __test.js.map
  | - otherfile.js
```

The problem is that it outputs the .map files to the same folder as .js files. Since I'll be having a lot of .js files, the folder will look cluttered.

Is there a possibility to make IntelliJ IDEA to output .map files to a specific folder? I couldn't find any info about that...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**tsc compiler** doesn't have options for this - `.map` files, when generated, are always placed to the same folder as `.js` files. 
See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html for the list of available options.

if you like to move generated files to a different location, you can use build tools like Gulp, Grunt or Webpack. But, if you go this way, make sure that sourcemaps URL is properly generated (you need using `--mapRoot` cli option that controls the reference to the map file in the `.js` file to let the debugger know where to look for sourcemaps).

see [TypeScript tsconfig Output files in certain folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297600/typescript-tsconfig-output-files-in-certain-folders), for example

Answer (score 0):

in the Typescript Compiler options... I added `--outDir ./.map`.  This affects both `.js` and `.js.map` files.